# Unit testing AngularJS with $httpBackend gives "Error: Unexpected Request"

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, httpbackend

I'm gonna preface this question by saying I've already gotten a test to work for my "LoginCtrl" which performs almost the exact same task.  I'm sure this is an issue of something really small I've overlooked.  Thanks in advance for any help :)

I've set the expected value/response for `httpBackend` for my test, but when I run `httpBackend.flush()`, it's as if I never set the expectation.

Testing code:

```
describe('user register', function () {
    var scope, RegisterCtrl, httpBackend, userJohnDoe, userJohnDoeRegistered, Restangular;


    // TEST
    beforeEach(module('LR.User.Register'));


    describe('RegisterCtrl', function () {
        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$httpBackend_, $rootScope, _Restangular_, $state) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            Restangular = _Restangular_;

            // Models
            userJohnDoeRegistered = {
                "access_token": "YzEyZDhjNjBlY2EwMTMxMmQzZGIzYWY5NDY4OGYwMjMzMGVjNDU3MDVhY2U0YjJmNDc1ODI3NWU0ODkzZGNkMQ",
                "expires_in": 7200,
                "token_type": "bearer",
                "scope": null,
                "refresh_token": "MmFhMTQ5NzU4ODI5ZjE2Mjk3ZjNlYzEwYzJkMjc4M2NkZjY2MjVkMjIwNWQzODUxYWNiYzY3NzIyMzEwYzJhNg",
                "user": {
                    "username": "johndoe",
                    "email": "johndoe@test.net",
                    "id": 1,
                    "first_name": "John",
                    "middle_name": "f",
                    "last_name": "Doe",
                    "created": "2013-09-04T10:46:10-0500",
                    "updated": "2013-09-04T10:46:10-0500"
                },
                "status": "success",
                "status_code": 200,
                "status_text": "OK"
            };
            userJohnDoe = {
                "email": "johndoe@test.net",
                "first_name": "John",
                "middle_name": "f",
                "last_name": "Doe",
                password: 'test123X',
                passwordSecond: 'test123X',
                client_id: '1_3b5zgimwg4kkko4wksk4sw0o48040o8ws8og8kg4wsowwkc44s'
            };

            httpBackend.whenPOST('/register', userJohnDoe).respond(userJohnDoeRegistered);


            RegisterCtrl = $controller('RegisterCtrl', {$scope: scope, $state: $state, Restangular: Restangular});
        }));
        afterEach(function () {
            httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });


        it('should be able to register a fake user', inject(function () {
            var resolvedRegistration;
            var cb = function (response) {
                // Expect the userJohnDoe object
                resolvedRegistration = sanitizeRestangularOne(response);

                console.log(logTestHeader('REGISTRATION RESPONSE') +
                    JSON.stringify(resolvedRegistration, null, '   '));
            };

            // Set credentials
            scope.user = userJohnDoeCredentials;

            // Call login
            var register = scope.register_user().then(function() {
                cb();
            });
            scope.$digest();
            httpBackend.flush();
            expect(resolvedRegistration).toEqual(userJohnDoeRegistered);
        }));
    });


});
```

Output response:

```
Chrome 29.0.1547 (Mac OS X 10.8.4) user register RegisterCtrl should be able to register a fake user FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: POST /register
    No more request expected
        at Error (<anonymous>)
        at $httpBackend (/Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:959:9)
        at y (/Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:64:282)
        at g (/Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:62:272)
        at r (/Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:96:140)
        at r (/Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:96:140)
        at /Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:97:293
        at Object.g.$eval (/Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:104:502)
        at Object.g.$digest (/Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:102:419)
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/src/app/user/register/register.spec.js:74:19)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.jasmine.window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1781:25)
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/src/app/user/register/register.spec.js:57:54)
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/src/app/user/register/register.spec.js:9:5)
        at /Users/bobothefrofro/Development/lr-phoenix/phoenix-client/src/app/user/register/register.spec.js:1:1
```

Comment: Figured out the problem, see my answer for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what it was.  my `register_user()` function was referencing `$scope.user`, which was being set to an undefined variable: `userJohnDoeCredentials` (a different variable name I had used for my previous test).

Not sure why my IDE wasn't complaining about me referencing an undefined variable, and it was passing all of my jslint tests, so that's strange too, but meh.  It's fixed :D Only if now I could get the mock request to return what I want it to...

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. I feel your pain on mocks. They are a whole different animal.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought is that something is making a request when you instantiate your controller. Maybe try adding the $httpBackend.flush() after your controller declaration line and see if that solves it. Also, should your $scope.$digest be after the $httpBackend.flush instead of before?

Comment: Tried moving the `flush()` call around, but anytime it's called before `digest()` I get a "No pending request to flush!" error. 

It seems to me like my `httpBackend.whenPOST` declaration isn't firing for whatever reason

Comment: By default my controller calls a request method which is what was causing this issue for me.